gpt-4o model provider errror
I am working on a projejct and when i run an X function, it fails. When I log my eventData, I get an error "Failed to find a model provider for model [gpt-4o]. Is it because I'm not a paid user? If yes, then how can I downgrade it to gpt-3.5? I'm using openAI keys ...
I attempted to generate a story using the gpt-4o model in my Story Teller AI application. I expected a successful story generation, but instead, the process failed and returned an error message indicating a missing model provider for gpt-4o. I suspect this might be related to my non-paid status, and I'm inquiring about downgrading to gpt-3.5 as a potential solution

The error message "Failed to find a model provider for model gpt-4o" means your application is trying to use a model that isn't available in your current OpenAI plan.
If you're not on a paid plan or your plan doesn't include access to newer models like GPT-4 or "GPT-4o" then you can use the GPT-3.5 model instead.
To downgrade to using GPT-3.5 change the model name in your code where you're calling the OpenAI API. Here’s how you might do it::
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

openai.createCompletion({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo", // Change this from gpt-4o to gpt-3.5-turbo
  prompt: "Sample prompt",
  maxTokens: 150, // optional
});


Add this line to your gpt script :
model: gpt-3.5-turbo
But anyway, I did it and got the famous "You exceeded your current quota" before even creating my first story...

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you are using the API, you need to be a paid user.  While you can downgrade to gpt-3.5-turbo or even gpt-3.5-turbo-16k as a free user, the rate limits are terrible and I have done enough to see that the results are very different.  I have run code as a free user and a paid user for Turbo (not 16k) and the increase in quality for a paid user is significant.  Now the OpenAI folks claim it is exactly the same but the results are clear.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
